# JBoss AS 7.1.1 application detect "Slow HTTP Denial of Service Attack"

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss7.x

I have a Java Web project deployed under Jboss as 7.1.1, After I checked the project with Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner, it alerted that "slow HTTP Denial of Service Attack", this is the screenshot of the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHjip.png)

I know that about tomcat or jboss4 modify server.xml can work, the default connectionTimeout is 20000, after set it as 8000 the problem solved.

```
<Connector port="8080" address="0.0.0.0"    
  maxThreads="250" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
  emptySessionPath="true" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
  connectionTimeout="8000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

So in order to decrease the connectionTImeout of Jboss7, I modified the standalone.xml like this

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.DEFAULT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT" value="2000"/>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT" value="1000"/>
</system-properties>
```

but it not work, the problem "slow HTTP Denial of Service Attack" is still exist. 
Thanks & Regards.
Forest

Comment: The problem might be that you're using version 7.1.1, this link seems to hint you need minimally 7.1.2: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/228773 .

Comment: But I can't find an available download link from the internet, Can you give me a link that I can download. Thanks

Comment: Correct, there is no community download. You either upgrade to JBoss EAP and pay a premium price, you compile it yourself from source or you upgrade to WildFly rather than sticking with the outdated JBoss 7.x code base. I would very much recommend going for WildFly.

Comment: As you said, I updated jboss 7.1.1 to WildFly, the problem solved. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is further proof that JBoss used to "release" alpha versions of their application server to the public for free prior to WildFly, this is a missing feature in the last downloadable binary release of JBoss 7.1.1 and was added in 7.1.2 which was only available through a commercial EAP build.

There are basically three paths to go to not be stuck with such an outdated alpha build of the application server.

1. buy an EAP license so you can get updated binary distributions of the application server and support
2. compile the latest version yourself from source as documented here: http://blog.kaltepoth.de/posts/2013/02/12/building-jboss-as7.html

   Source is downloadable here: https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/releases
3. upgrade to WildFly and leave the past behind

It is very much recommended to just go for WildFly; it is the same base application server as Jboss 7.x with the same configuration characteristics and the same set of API specification implementations (Hibernate/RestEasy/Weld/etc.), but properly updated.

Comment: I think compile a JBoss 7.1.3 is a best idea for me, now I have solve the problem, Thank you Gimby!

Comment: There is no reason to stick with outdated tech, you're only setting yourself up for misery. If you must stick with Jboss 7.x for any reason I really cannot think of, compile the latest version and not 7.1.3. There have been so many bugfixes you will be missing otherwise.

Comment: I know that select a outdated version is not a good idea, even if I fixed the problem, there are still many exist. But I have no a better method, because the project the server deployed is old for jdk6, In order to deploy it without a big changes, so i select 7.x . WildFly is bases on jdk7, EAP should buy the license. After it I will try to use WildFly. Thank you .